# How do you construct a class object that is taking parameters from form control values?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C#. I'm trying to use a constructor to instantiate an object that is taking parameters from the form controls(NumericUpDown, and two CheckBoxes).

Usually I instantiate objects in the generate Form class, but when I try and pass the values from the form controls it says it can't access them.

I have the same instantiation under  InitializeComponent(); but that doesn't create the object.

```
namespace DinnerParty
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


    //Usually instantiate here, but in this case my constructor is taking input from the control on the form. I'm getting errors saying it cant
    DinnerParty lanparty = new DinnerParty((int)NumberUpDown1.Value, CheckBoxHealth.Checked, CheckBoxDecotations.Checked);

    public Form1()
    {


        InitializeComponent();
        //putting the instantiation here doesn't create the object. 
        DinnerParty lanparty = new DinnerParty((int)NumberUpDown1.Value, CheckBoxHealth.Checked, CheckBoxDecotations.Checked);


        DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
    }
```

edit: I took Ryan's advice but it is now saying the object I'm referencing 
in the DisplayDinnerPartyCost() method is null. Below is more relevant 
code

```
//This is the constructor, its taking the int and bool values from the 
instantiation statement
public DinnerParty(int numberOfPeople, bool healthyOption, bool 
fancyDecorations)
        {
            NumberOfPeople = numberOfPeople;
            HealthyOption = healthyOption;
            FancyDecorations = fancyDecorations;
        }
//Here are the properties that are being set by the constructor            
public int NumberOfPeople { get; set; }
public bool FancyDecorations { get; set; }                                 
public bool HealthyOption { get; set; }
//Here is the method that is throwing the null object error, its saying that lanparty.Cost is null
public void DisplayDinnerPartyCost()
        {
           decimal cost = lanparty.Cost;
           labelRetrunCost.Text = cost.ToString("c");
        }
//Here is the encapsulation that calculates the cost
 public decimal Cost { get
            {
                decimal totalcost = CalculateDecorations(FancyDecorations);
                totalcost += 
((CalculateCostOfBeveragesPerPerson(HealthyOption) + CostOfFoodPerPerson) * 
NumberOfPeople);

                if (HealthyOption)
                {
                    totalcost *= .95M;
                    return totalcost;
                }
                else
                {
                    return totalcost;
                }

            }


        }
```

edit: Here's the entire class and form code

```
    //class
    namespace DinnerParty
    {
        public class DinnerParty
        {
            public const int CostOfFoodPerPerson = 25;
            public int NumberOfPeople { get; set; }
            public bool FancyDecorations { get; set; }
            public bool HealthyOption { get; set; }
            public decimal Cost { get
                {
                    decimal totalcost = CalculateDecorations(FancyDecorations);
                totalcost += 
((CalculateCostOfBeveragesPerPerson(HealthyOption) + CostOfFoodPerPerson) * 
NumberOfPeople);

                if (HealthyOption)
                {
                    totalcost *= .95M;
                    return totalcost;
                }
                else
                {
                    return totalcost;
                }


            }


        }



        public DinnerParty(int numberOfPeople, bool healthyOption, bool 
fancyDecorations)
        {
            NumberOfPeople = numberOfPeople;
            HealthyOption = healthyOption;
            FancyDecorations = fancyDecorations;
        }

        private decimal CalculateDecorations(bool fancy)
        {
            decimal CostDeco;
            if (FancyDecorations)
            {
                 CostDeco = (NumberOfPeople * 15.00M) + 50M;
                return CostDeco;
            }
            else
            {
                 CostDeco = (NumberOfPeople * 7.50M) + 30M;
                return CostDeco;
            }
        }

        private decimal CalculateCostOfBeveragesPerPerson(bool Health)
        {
            if (HealthyOption)
            {
                decimal CostOfBeverages = 5.00M;
                return CostOfBeverages;

            }
            else
            {
                decimal CostOfBeverages = 20.00M;
                return CostOfBeverages;
            }
        }



    }
}
//Form code
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {



        DinnerParty lanparty = null; 




        public Form1()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();
            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             lanparty = new DinnerParty((int)NumberUpDown1.Value, 
CheckBoxHealth.Checked, CheckBoxDecotations.Checked);

            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
        }


        public void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lanparty.NumberOfPeople = (int) NumberUpDown1.Value;
            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();    
        }

        public void CheckBoxDecotations_CheckedChanged(object sender, 
EventArgs e)
        {
            lanparty.FancyDecorations = CheckBoxDecotations.Checked;
            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
        }

        public void CheckBoxHealth_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
e)
        {
            lanparty.HealthyOption = CheckBoxHealth.Checked;
            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
        }

        public void DisplayDinnerPartyCost()
        {
           decimal cost = lanparty.Cost;
           labelRetrunCost.Text = cost.ToString("c");
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: You need to share the code of `DisplayDinnerPartyCost` method. Also share which line of code gives the error ?

Comment: @Officer_Narc - This isn't a [mcve]. I need to be able to copy, paste, and compile your code.

Comment: @Officer_Narc - We need to see complete classes that require a minimal amount of work for us to compile. Can you do that?

Comment: You are initializing the object in your form load event, while you are using the object in method call from constructor (constructor code will be called before form load and hence your new error

Comment: You need to remove `DisplayDinnerPartyCost();` from `Form1()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your complete code shows that you have this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
}
```

That code executes before `Form_Load` so `lanparty` is still `null` at that stage.

If you write your code like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lanparty = new DinnerParty((int)NumberUpDown1.Value, CheckBoxHealth.Checked, CheckBoxDecotations.Checked);
    DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
}
```

...it should work fine.

---

I've done some refactoring of your code. You should make `DinnerParty` raise an event when the costs change. Then you only update your UI when that event fires. This ensures that `lanparty` must be populated.

Here's `DinnerParty`:

```
public class DinnerParty
{
    private int _numberOfPeople;
    private bool _fancyDecorations;
    private bool _healthyOption;

    public int CostOfFoodPerPerson { get; } = 25;

    public int NumberOfPeople
    {
        get => _numberOfPeople;
        set
        {
            _numberOfPeople = value;
            this.CostUpdated?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public bool FancyDecorations
    {
        get => _fancyDecorations;
        set
        {
            _fancyDecorations = value;
            this.CostUpdated?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public bool HealthyOption
    {
        get => _healthyOption;
        set
        {
            _healthyOption = value;
            this.CostUpdated?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler CostUpdated;

    public DinnerParty(int numberOfPeople, bool healthyOption, bool fancyDecorations)
    {
        this._numberOfPeople = numberOfPeople;
        this._healthyOption = healthyOption;
        this._fancyDecorations = fancyDecorations;
    }

    public decimal Cost
    {
        get
        {
            decimal decorations = CalculateDecorations(_fancyDecorations);
            decimal costOfBeveragesPerPerson = CalculateCostOfBeveragesPerPerson(_healthyOption);
            decimal costPerPerson = costOfBeveragesPerPerson + this.CostOfFoodPerPerson;
            decimal totalcost = costPerPerson * _numberOfPeople + decorations;

            if (_healthyOption)
            {
                totalcost *= .95M;
            }

            return totalcost;
        }
    }

    private decimal CalculateDecorations(bool fancy)
    {
        decimal per = _fancyDecorations ? 15m : 7.5m;
        decimal flat = _fancyDecorations ? 50m : 30m;
        return _numberOfPeople * per + flat;
    }

    private decimal CalculateCostOfBeveragesPerPerson(bool Health)
        => _healthyOption ? 5m : 20m;
}
```

And here's your `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    DinnerParty lanparty = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lanparty = new DinnerParty((int)NumberUpDown1.Value, CheckBoxHealth.Checked, CheckBoxDecotations.Checked);
        lanparty.CostUpdated += lanparty_CostUpdated;
        DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
    }

    private void lanparty_CostUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lanparty.NumberOfPeople = (int)NumberUpDown1.Value;
    }

    private void CheckBoxDecotations_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lanparty.FancyDecorations = CheckBoxDecotations.Checked;
    }

    private void CheckBoxHealth_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lanparty.HealthyOption = CheckBoxHealth.Checked;
    }

    public void DisplayDinnerPartyCost()
    {
        decimal cost = lanparty.Cost;
        labelRetrunCost.Text = cost.ToString("c");
    }
}
```

Just a small side-note: it seems weird that the cost of decorations is also discounted when someone chooses the healthy option. Maybe something needs rethinking there?

Answer (score 3):

You have to wait until Form_Load is executed.

```
namespace DinnerParty
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DinnerParty lanparty = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Make sure to add event handler for Load
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lanparty = new DinnerParty((int)NumberUpDown1.Value,
                                       CheckBoxHealth.Checked,
                                       CheckBoxDecotations.Checked);
            DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
        }

        // Make sure that any code that references lanparty does not execute while it is null
        public void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lanparty != null)
            {
                lanparty.NumberOfPeople = (int) NumberUpDown1.Value;
                DisplayDinnerPartyCost();    
            }
        }

        public void CheckBoxDecotations_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lanparty != null)
            {
                lanparty.FancyDecorations = CheckBoxDecotations.Checked;
                DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
            }
        }

        public void CheckBoxHealth_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (lanparty != null)
            {
                lanparty.HealthyOption = CheckBoxHealth.Checked;
                DisplayDinnerPartyCost();
            }
        }

        // You may need a functions like this, depending on how your code works
        private void GetLanPartyConfiguration()
        {
            if (lanparty != null)
            {
                lanparty.NumberOfPeople = (int) NumberUpDown1.Value;
                lanparty.HealthyOption = CheckBoxHealth.Checked;
                lanparty.FancyDecorations = CheckBoxDecotations.Checked;
            }
        }

        private void SetLanPartyControls()
        {
            if (lanparty != null)
            {
                NumberUpDown1.Value = lanparty.NumberOfPeople;
                CheckBoxHealth.Checked = lanparty.HealthyOption;
                CheckBoxDecotations.Checked = lanparty.FancyDecorations;
            }
        }

        public void DisplayDinnerPartyCost()
        {
            if (lanparty != null)
            {
                decimal cost = lanparty.Cost;
                labelRetrunCost.Text = cost.ToString("c");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason it still throws an error saying that lanparty is null. Which is confusing since the constructor should be making a new object at the forms load

Comment: @Officer_Narc - You really need to post a [mcve] if you need any more detail than Ryan's given you. At this point Ryan looks like he is correct, but something is happening in the code you haven't shown us so it's impossible to help without further information.

Comment: @Officer_Narc most likely you are trying to execute code before `lanparty` is initialized. You either need to wait to execute the code until `lanparty` is not null or protect the functions that access lanparty with something like: `if (lanparty == null) { return; }`